# Exception en Java Maven

Tags: java, maven, excepciones

Hice una pequeña aplicación para clase donde se gestiona un pequeño concesionario. Hice un `JFrame` con botones e iconos y funciona perfectamente. Está hecho bajo Java [ant](/questions/tagged/ant).

He intentado migrarlo a Java Maven. Para ello, he creado los mismos paquetes y en cada uno he copiado las clases tal y como estaban en el primer proyecto.

Al ejecutarlo me salta una excepción:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.toExternalForm()" because "location" is null

He debugueado y se donde está el error. Me salta en el `initComponent` cuando está buscando las imágenes de los iconos. Pero están situadas en el directorio raíz del paquete iconos.

```
private void initComponents() {

    lTitulo = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    panelPrincipal = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    bSalir = new javax.swing.JButton();
    bRecuperarVehiculosDNI = new javax.swing.JButton();
    bNuevoPropietario = new javax.swing.JButton();
    bBorrarPropietario = new javax.swing.JButton();
    bNuevoVehiculo = new javax.swing.JButton();
    bBorrarVehiculo = new javax.swing.JButton();
    bActualizarPropietario = new javax.swing.JButton();
    bRecTodosVehiculos = new javax.swing.JButton();
    bMarcas = new javax.swing.JButton();
    bSoloVehiculos = new javax.swing.JButton();
    bPropietarios = new javax.swing.JButton();
    lConexion = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    lConsultas = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    lTitulo.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Segoe UI Black", 0, 24)); // NOI18N
    lTitulo.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    lTitulo.setText("CONCESIONARIO DESOBRIGA S.L");

    panelPrincipal.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 153, 153));

    bSalir.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/iconos/exit.png"))); // NOI18N
    bSalir.setText("Salir");
    bSalir.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            bSalirActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    bRecuperarVehiculosDNI.setText("Vehículos de un DNI");
    bRecuperarVehiculosDNI.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            bRecuperarVehiculosDNIActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    bNuevoPropietario.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/iconos/newPropietario.png"))); // NOI18N
    bNuevoPropietario.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            bNuevoPropietarioActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
```

¿Qué porque se que el error es al localizarme los iconos? Por ejemplo elimino el icono del botón `bSalir` y el debug continúa de frente, hasta encontrar el siguiente icono el cual me hace saltar la misma excepción.

¿Por qué demonios me lanza esa excepción? Los iconos están copiados en la carpeta `src` del nuevo proyecto, en la carpeta que pertenece al paquete iconos.

Answer (score 0):

La solución es que cualquier archivo que no sea .java hay que meterlo en la carpeta /src/main/resources cuando estamos en Java Maven.